# Specify file extension with argparse

Tags: python, argparse, file-extension

I would like to specify several file extensions with argparse.

I have tried the code below but it doesn't work.  How do I specify multiple file extensions with argparse?

```
parser.add_argument('file', action = 'store', type = argparse.FileType('r'), choices=["*.aaa", "*.bbb"])
```

EDIT : I have found my own solution using string type instead of FileType :

```
def input_ok(string):
    if not os.path.exists(string):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Filename %r doesn\'t exists in this directory." % string)

    if string[-4:] != ".aaa" and string[-4:] != ".bbb":
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%r is not a .aaa or a .bbb file." % string)
return string
```

...

```
parser.add_argument('input_path', action = 'store',
    type = input_ok, #argparse.FileType('r'), #choices=["*.stl", "*.csv"])
```

Answer (score 4):

The crux of the problem is how [choices](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#choices) work. Argparse first builds a list of the passed arguments and does type conversion, then it checks for inclusion in choices with the `in` operator. This means it won't do any pattern matching (to match `'*.aaa'`) but checks for string equality. Instead we can make our own container to pass to choices.

Without using `argparse.Filetype` it looks like this. Argparse also needs the container to have `__iter__` to make the Metavar tuple for the help message.

```
class Choices():
    def __init__(self, *choices):
        self.choices = choices

    def __contains__(self, choice):
        # True if choice ends with one of self.choices
        return any(choice.endswith(c) for c in self.choices)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.choices)

parser.add_argument('file', action='store', choices=Choices('.aaa', '.bbb'))
```

You can extend this idea to do pretty much anything by changing `__contains__` to suit your needs. For example, if you also passed `type=argparse.FileType('r')` then argparse will convert to a file object before checking inclusion.

```
def __contains__(self, choice):
    # choice is now a file object
    return any(choice.name.endswith(c) for c in self.choices)
```

---

As an aside, this is why I hate argparse. It's overly complex and tries to do way more than it should. I don't think validation should be done in the argument parser. Use [docopt](http://docopt.org/) and validate things yourself.

Comment: `argparse` gives you some tools for argument validation, but does not require you to use them.  `FileType` is a convenience feature, intended for use in common scripting applications. You don't have to use it if it does not fit your application.  Same goes for `choices`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with `argparse` accepting a string, and you doing your own validation after.  Sometimes you want to check if a filename is correct, but not open it until later (e.g. using `with open(filename) as f:`).  This is likely to be the simplest method.

An alternative to `kalhartt's` `Choices` class would be to use `os.path` or `glob` to get a list of allowable files.

```
p.add_argument('file',choices=glob.glob('*.txt'))
In [91]: p.parse_args('test.txt'.split())
Out[91]: Namespace(file='test.txt')
```

A problem with this is that the help and error messages can be excessively long, listing all of the allowable filenames.

This `choices` does not work along with `FileType`.  That's because it tests against choices after the file has been opened

```
p.add_argument('file',choices=[open('test.txt')],type=argparse.FileType('r'))
p.parse_args('test.txt'.split())
# usage: python [-h] {<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0xa102f98>}
# error: argument file: invalid choice: <open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0xa102f40>
# (choose from <open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0xa102f98>)
```

Even  though the filenames are the same, the ids of the two opened files are not the same.  As`kalhartt's` example shows, the `choices` object will have to have a custom `__contains__` function (one that tests the file name, e.g. `f.name.endswith('txt')`).

But if you really like the fact that `FileType` opens the file, I can imagine subclassing it, so it checks for extensions.

```
class FileTypeWithExtension(argparse.FileType):
    def __init__(self, mode='r', bufsize=-1, extension=None):
        self._extension = extension
        super(FileTypeWithExtension, self).__init__()
    def __call__(self, string):
        if string != '-' and self._extension:
            if not string.endswith(self._extension):
               # just testing against one extension for now
               raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('wrong extension')
        return super(FileTypeWithExtension, self).__call__(string)

p.add_argument('file',type=FileTypeWithExtension('r',extension='txt'))
p.parse_args('test.tst'.split())
#usage: ipython [-h] file
#ipython: error: argument file: wrong extension

p.parse_args('test.txt'.split())
# Namespace(file=<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0xa13ce90>)
```